# Notice: Undefined variable: on insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to PHP and ran into a problem. I am trying to check if an id exists in the table and if not then insert the records but running into trouble. I currently have:

```
            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['add'])){
            $id              = $_POST['id'];
            $first_name      = $_POST['first_name'];
            $last_name       = $_POST['last_name'];
            $dob             = $_POST['dob'];
            $telephone       = $_POST['telephone'];
            $job_title       = $_POST['job_title'];
            $site            = $_POST['site'];
            $department      = $_POST['department'];
            $email           = $_POST['email'];
            $pass1           = $_POST['pass1'];
            $pass2           = $_POST['pass2'];


            $cek = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id='$id'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($cek) == 0){

                if($pass1 == $pass2){
                    $pass = md5($pass1);
                    $insert = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO employees (id, first_name, last_name, dob, telephone, job_title, site, department, email, password)
                                                        VALUES('$id','$first_name', '$last_name', '$dob', '$telephone', '$job_title', '$site', '$department', '$email', '$pass')") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
                    if($insert){
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Employee added</div>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Ups, Error, user not added</div>';
                    }
                } else{
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Passwords do not match</div>';
                }
            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Employee Id Exists</div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

I am encountering a error: Notice: Undefined variable: db

I have tried to google but no avail so far. Anyone have any ideas?

The error points to line 76 which is

```
        $cek = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: You could do `WHERE id='{$id}'` but its a really bad way to go as it leaves you open for SQL Injections.

Comment: as the error suggests were did you set the $db variable? The Mysqli_query is trying to open up the database, but since $db seems to not be defined in your script  it wont be able to open a connection.

Comment: I have 
<?php include("config.php");?> with the $db variable set there

Comment: @RobWilson, are you 100% sure that the config.php is beign included properly? and how is the DB variable declared in that file?  Could you include it for us to see?

Comment: I should say I'm a numpty, missing the < from the above statement. Fixed now, Thanks for your help, was looking at it for an hour and its always something obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had < missing from the very start of the code

?php include("config.php");?>

instead of

One of those its right there but just couldn't see it missing. Must have knocked delete by accident or something and not noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a link](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_query.asp) to help with the mysql connection

```
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

then you can use

```
 $cek = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id='$id'");
```

Hope that helps a little